# check date in gridview match with current date or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String MyConnection2 = "Server=localhost;database=ovs;Uid=root;password=; Convert Zero Datetime=True";
        DateTime time = DateTime.Today;              // Use current time
        GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
        Label lbleddate = (Label)grdrow.Cells[0].FindControl("lbleddatae");
        Label lblstdate= (Label)grdrow.Cells[0].FindControl("lblstdate");
        string sdate = lblstdate.Text;
        string edate = lbleddate.Text;
        DateTime stdate= Convert.ToDateTime(sdate);
        DateTime eddate = Convert.ToDateTime(edate);

        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        
        if (!(time.Equals(edate)))
        {

            Label2.Text = "Please chenk the eletion date!";
        }

        else { 
           // execute query
    }
   }
```

[start date and end date store in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgvvM.png)
I would like the get the start date and end date display is gridview (label) and compare with the current date. If not equal to the start date and end date, display the error message "Please check the election date!". I facing the error which the current date is 21/10/2020 and the date start date and end date display in gridview is also 21/10/2020 but the error message will show and the query can't be executed.

Comment: Which error? Add debuggingdetails to your question.

Comment: Hello, there is no error message from the compiler, but the problem is even though the start date and end date in the gridview are the same as the current date, the error message will show.

Comment: Have you debugged your code to check that it's really the same? You are using datetimes, those not only contain date but also time, maybe the date part is the same but the time part is different. Try `if(time.Date != edate.Date)^

Comment: Hello, I examined the value in the edate is the correct one which is 10/21/2020, but for the time the value are 10/21/2020 12:00:00 AM. I had also tried the code you suggested, but both of date and edate will having the value 10/21/2020 12:00:00AM

Comment: Yes, that's what is supposed to do, it ignores the time part (sets to 12:00:00) so they are equal. Have you tried it? If both dates are equal then the "if" must not enter, will go to the "else".

Comment: OMG! It's work! Thank you very much! This is exactly what I want